# Make React Components Self-Aware of where they were imported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I am working on a site where I have some graphic components and some markdown files which imports those graphic components using webpack and mdx-loader. I have a page which maps over all the graphics and make a graphic list page and standalone individual graphic pages. I now want to show, in those individual graphic pages, links to all the pages which imported that graphic. Is there an automatic way of doing that using webpack or any react library?

OR

Simply, is there a way to find out in the React Component, the names of components where it was imported ?

Comment: You first have a list of all graphics. Then a separate page for each graphic. Why would a graphic be used in multiple places? It seems 1:1 the way its worded.

Comment: Two markdown files can import the same graphics. Moreover the graphics are made by people proficient in JavaScript but the MDX files are not. I would like the graphics to show the places they were imported without asking the people who make the MDX file